# Dynamic/Random questions on Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I have a set of 100 questions with multiple choice answers that user have to answer to. I want a random set of 5 or 10 questions to be given to the user each time they open the Google form and store the user response for those 5/10 questions.

The questions are feedback based and hence I do not need to collect the user data, etc. I just need to be able to throw 5 or 10 random questions from the set of 100 everytime a user loads the Google form.

I am new to Google form but I could not find any resource supporting the same. Can this be done on Google form? Is there an easy alternative?

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I am also looking to do the same.

Comment: Nope, sadly we did not find any support around that. Created our own form then.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in solution that allows you to randomize questions (at least not yet); but you might be able to pull this off with a script that modifies the form using either an onFormSubmit trigger or a time-based trigger.

First you create a form with the pool of 100 questions and break those questions into individual sections with one question per section. Then create an initial branching scheme that connects a subset of those sections.

Then write a script on the form that randomizes the branching scheme/order either on form submit or periodically using a time-based trigger.

Its probably not trivial to implement but its possible.