# Can I script a quiz to generate different questions for different users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to script a quiz which will be shows some questions from a question bank. And Also need to randomize question for each user.

**As an example** :

*A Question Bank has four questions [q01, q02, q03, q04]*

*Mr.A should be given q01 and q02 only*

*Mr.B should be given q03 and q01 only*

(With same link)

**Is it possible ?**

Thank You..

Comment: Are you looking for [`Form.setShuffleQuestions`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setShuffleQuestions(Boolean)) option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic/Random questions on Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786137/dynamic-random-questions-on-google-form)

Comment: Not just shuffle